# Return average using same table data

Tags: postgresql, query, subquery

I've got this query I'm testing with:

```
select sum(units) / (select count(distinct week) from record_sales_data where customer_country_id=2 group by customer_country_id) as average
from record_sales_data
where customer_country_id=2
group by week,customer_country_id
```

Which returns what I want for country 2 of course. Now I'd like to return the average for ALL countries, but I don't seem to find a way to return by all countries, grouped by country id..

In the example above, here's what country 2 looks like in the raw data: (there are many more countries of course)

```
year|month|week|customer_country_id|units|
----|-----|----|-------------------|-----|
2020|    5|  21|                  2|    1|
2020|    5|  21|                  2|   36|
2020|    5|  22|                  2|   -1|
2020|    5|  22|                  2|   -1|
```

I apologize if this is a simple to resolve question but I'm still learning SQL and can't figure out an easy way to come up with a solution to this.

Thanks!

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it by doing this:

```
select sum(units) / (select count(distinct week) from record_sales_data rs2 where rs.customer_country_id=rs2.customer_country_id group by customer_country_id) as average
from record_sales_data rs
group by customer_country_id
```